# How can I clear MS Access controls for most of a form, but not all of it?

Tags: microsoft-access

How can I clear access controls for most of a form but not all?
I have one control (Combo55) that I would like to reset rather than clear but am unsure how to change my command to do it. Here's the code as it stands:

```
Private Sub Command2061_Click()
'Clear

Const cstrPrompt As String = _
    "Are you sure you want to Clear this Form? Yes/No"
    If MsgBox(cstrPrompt, vbQuestion + vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        Dim Ctl As Control
        On Error Resume Next
        For Each Ctl In Me.Controls
        Ctl.Value = Null
        Next Ctl

End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test the name for each control and do what you want instead

```
Private Sub Command2061_Click()
'Clear

Const cstrPrompt As String = _
    "Are you sure you want to Clear this Form? Yes/No"
    If MsgBox(cstrPrompt, vbQuestion + vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        Dim Ctl As Control
        On Error Resume Next
        For Each Ctl In Me.Controls
        If Ctl.Name = "Combo55" Then
            'Your action here
            'Ctl.Value = "reset value"
        Else
            Ctl.Value = Null
        End if
        Next Ctl

End If
End Sub
```